# Outlook Add-in project with Identity server 4 Authentication, fails to connect with identity server

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, outlook-addin, identityserver4

I have developed an Outlook add-in project for Outlook desktop app with identity server authentication, but it fails to access the identity server through code for authentication.

Below is the code to connect with identity server

```
return await this.http.post('https://localhost:5050/connect/token', body, { headers : headers})
    .pipe(map(response => {
      debugger;      
       let result = response.json();
       if (result && result['access_token']) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', result['access_token']);
          return true; 
       }
       else return false; 
     }));
```

---

Following is the full code of the function

```
async login(credentials) { 
    let body = `grant_type=password&username=${credentials['username']}&password=${credentials['password']}&scope=api1`;
    let headers = new Headers({'Authorization' : 'Basic cm8uY2xpZW50OnNlY3JldDI='}); 
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers : headers});
    return await this.http.post('https://localhost:5050/connect/token', body, { headers : headers})
    .pipe(map(response => {           
       let result = response.json();            
       if (result && result['access_token']) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', result['access_token']);          
          return true; 
       }
       else return false; 
     }));     

   }
```

Note:

App is designed for Outlook Desktop App and not for Outlook365 online.
Identity server runs in HTTPS.

When connects with the add-in through Outlook, login page loads successfully but when entering user name and password to log, the above code fails to connect with identity server.

Identity server is implemented in a separate project, runs in HTTPS and it works fine when running the web application without implementing it as an Outlook add-in project.

The same Outlook adding project works fine if there is no identity server authentication implemented.
Can access any APIs runs in Identity server which runs in HTTPS,
ex -  https://localhost:5050/api/User

but when calling 'https://localhost:5050/connect/token' to get the taken, no response and Token cannot be received

Could you please any idea to solve the above problem to develop Outlook add-in with identity server authentication

Comment: What request parameters are you passing to the Token Endpoint (connect/token)?

Comment: pass user name and password

Comment: Are you passing `grant_type` and `client_id` as well?

Comment: Yes, I edited the above question with full code, you can see it Sir

Comment: you are missing `client_id`.  This is not optional for the Token Endpoint.  Can you also give details of the response you are getting? What is the error? do you have the identity server logging?

Comment: Thanks Sir, added client_id and removed the async, now it is working. Thanks for help